# How to url if I have this piece of code as my controller

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting

All my pages homepage.php, about.php, contact.php are in a folder pages. The index.php on the root directory controls what pages to load based on user input.

```
<?php
// Defualt page will always be pages/homepage.html, if not, change this to the name of the file you have created to be the homepage.
$page = 'homepage';

// Get pages based on user input 
if (!empty($_GET['name'])) {
//Assign a variable to a sanitised version of the data passed in the URL
$tmp_page = basename($_GET['name']); 
//If the file exists, update $page
if (file_exists("pages/{$tmp_page}.php")) 
    $page = $tmp_page;
//If the file does not exist, include notfound page and exit  
elseif(!file_exists($tmp_page)){
    include 'pages/notfound.php';
    exit;
    }
}
// Include $page (declared default)
include ("pages/$page.php");
?>
```

The default page on the index.php is the homepage.php which fetches products from the products table and displays it.

The homepage.php in the folder pages.

```
<?php 
$dbquery = "SELECT * FROM lbtbl_products";
$productresult = $dbconnect->query($dbquery);

if ($productresult->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $productresult->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
    <div class="prod-cnt prod-box">
    <form method="post" action="cartupdate.php">
    <h3 class="prod-title">
    <a href="productdetail.php?id=<?php echo $row['lbproductId'];?>"><?php echo $row["lbproductName"]; ?></a>
    </h3>
    <p><?php echo $row["lbproductDescription"];?></p>
    <div class="price-cnt">
    <div class="prod-price"><img src="images/common/rupees.png" width="7" height="10"/> <?php echo $row["lbproductPrice"];?></div>
    Qty <input type="text" name="product_qty" value="1" size="3" />
    <button class="add_to_cart">Add To Cart</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="<?php echo $row["lbproductSku"];?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="add" />
    </div>
</form>
</div>
<?php }
    } else {
    echo "0 results";
    }
    $dbconnect->close(); ?>
```

Everything works fine up till now.

What I need to do is display product details when a user clicks the product so I added a productdetails.php to the pages directory which gets the ID of the product and displays the details.

The problem:- If the productdetails.php is saved on the root directory it works perfectly but when I move the productdetails.php to the pages folder (where all other pages homepage, aboutus, contactus resides) a 404, not found error is shown.

I know it has something to do with the index.php. Can anyone help?

Comment: do you use .htaccess ? Is your project url look like this http://yourproject/homepage ?

Comment: @Nahid, yes it does use .htaccess Nahid. No the homepage is set as default but the subsequent pages does comes up like www.abc.com/contact

Answer (score 0):

Use this type URL
www.abc.com/productdetails?product_id=1

Then your routing system search productdetails.php are exist in pages directory. If exist then load the page and then you can find the product by using the product id $_GET['product_id']

Maybe it will work